# Checking of open LOBs in EXCEPTION block

Tags: oracle, plsql

By practice, I check opened cursors in EXCEPTION block.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR curUSERS IS
    SELECT USERNAME FROM
    USERS;
BEGIN
    OPEN curUSERS;
    --statements truncated
    CLOSE curUSERS;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF curUSERS%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE curUSERS;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I tried it on LOBs (BLOB, CLOB, and BFILE) but when I threw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception, it also threw an Invalid LOB Locator exception.

```
DECLARE
    objBFILE BFILE NOT NULL DEFAULT BFILENAME('DIR_USERS', 'user.jpg');
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(objBFILE);
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(objBFILE);
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DBMS_LOB.ISOPEN(objBFILE)=1 THEN
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(objBFILE);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Is there a good way to check for opened LOBs like cursors?
I want to close opened LOBs if an exception occurs.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but you should almost never use code like your first block.  Implicit cursors are easier, safer, and faster than explicit cursors.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2191679?start=0&tstart=0). Just include if the objBFILE is not null. It worked!

```
IF objBFILE IS NOT NULL
    AND DBMS_LOB.ISOPEN(objBFILE)=1 THEN
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(objBFILE);
END IF;
```